# Whats the fastest way to draw and update graphics using the least resources?

Tags: c++, performance, graphics

I want to learn to start drawing graphics, but I'm confused about where I should start. I know I could jump into learning OpenGL or DirectX but I want to know what other options exists for drawing graphics, and how well they scale against OpenGL performance wise.
C++ commands to draw pixels directly to the screen make me question just how the graphics rendering process is done, and if just using these C++ commands might be better performance wise for small things (like drawing a custom window).

I'm really unsure about where to start, so an objective comparison between any popular graphics rendering software/techniques would be quite helpful.

Comment: If you're just starting, performance is the least of your concerns.

Comment: Thats not true at all, if I learn to do things one way and it's a terrible method of doing things then I'll have to re-learn it the other way or continue doing things the bad way.

Comment: @user1958850 I partly agree. But you shouldn't say "I don't want to learn software-rendering because I know that hardware-rendering performs better". You should (and your question reads that you want to) learn different methods.

Comment: A method's measure of terrible is more than just its performance. What's important is the concepts you'll learn and how to implement them differently depending on the situation. A bad programmer is instantly marked as one that tries (tried) to pick the One True Way and never looks anywhere else. Pick the method that'll teach you the concepts best, not draw something the fastest.

Comment: what does resource mean?  $ you have to invest in it?  time you have to invest in it?  memory requirement?  processing requirement?  time it takes to build.. etc etc

Comment: I'm voting to close this as "not constructive", I'm afraid. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask] says "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.", and there *are* entire books written about this topic. There's no single, definitive answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there are a couple of methods on how to draw stuff on a screen or in an image.

- **Hardware rendering** (OpenGL)
  To start learning OpenGL you should read the tutorial ["Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming"](https://web.archive.org/web/20150309070928/http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/). The tutorial is *very* good; it explains all the necessary math, starts with easy examples and cares about performance. And it is very modern (if you google for "OpenGL tutorial", you find a lot of old tutorials which use the ancient "fixed pipeline method").
- **Software rendering**
  I'd personally recommend to use the [Qt framework](http://qt-project.org) for this task. (But there are also other libraries which can do that, of course.)
  Create a new QImage or QPixmap object and a QPainter on it. Then, you can draw with the QPainter commands on the image. You can then save the image to a file or show it on the screen. You can also render directly on the screen using a QPainter in a custom [paint event](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwidget.html#paintEvent).
- **Custom per-pixel drawing**
  Use this method to learn the "low-level" stuff of computer graphics. Learn how to draw lines on the screen if the only operations provided by a library are "set pixel x,y to color r,g,b". This can also be done using Qt's [QImage::setPixel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#setPixel-2).

Comment: Actually, they abandoned the plan to move widgets to OpenGL rendering for Qt5. (Of course, the new QtQuick2 stuff is OpenGL based.)

Comment: @Slavik81 Well, the "default GUI" in Qt5 is QML2. ;) But yeah, I meant QtWidgets in the first place and thought that they are rendered using OpenGL now. Thanks for the pointer.